# how to display image in jquery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i am using Jquery Grid fetching images using Jquery Grid so far i am fetching Image path from server but i dont know how to display image in image source.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            // prepare the data
            var theme = 'classic';
            var imagerenderer = function(row, datafield, value) {
                return '<img style="margin-left: 5px;" height="60" width="50" src="' + value + '"/>';
            }
            var source =
                    {
                        datatype: "json",
                        datafields: [
                            {name: 'ID'},
                            {name: 'name'}
                        ],
                        url: 'PaginationForWhiteAndBlackList.php',
                        root: 'Rows',
                        beforeprocessing: function(data)
                        {
                            source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;
                        }
                    };

            var dataadapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            // initialize jqxGrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                    {
                        width: 600,
                        source: dataadapter,
                        theme: theme,
                        autoheight: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        virtualmode: true,
                        rendergridrows: function()
                        {
                            return dataadapter.records;
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {text: 'ID', datafield: 'id', width: 250},
                            {text: 'Name', datafield: 'image', width: 200, cellsrenderer: imagerenderer}
                        ]
                    });
        });
```